# Parse Issue with the display of related relational values

Tags: swift, parse-platform, relational, pfquery, comments

Now I'm doing a normal topic and comment integrated app. Already carried out the functions like posting topic, posting comment, and setting the pointer of my comment to the Topic class. 
But now the problem that trouble me now for the past few days, is the comments displayed cannot be classified to each topic, they are all gathering together no matter what different topic they're from.

My PFObjects are Topics and Comment, two classes totally.
Topics has objects:Title, content and user.
Comment has objects: content, parent(pointer to Topics) and user.

Already check out the parse database, seeming like each comment has a same parent key from its own topic's object ID. But still wonder why they cannot be shown accordingly.

Here's my coding. I'd be grateful if ones could lend ones' helping hand.

```
var timelineCommentData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
func loadData(){
    timelineCommentData.removeAllObjects()

    var findCommentData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Comment")
    findCommentData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects:[AnyObject]!,error:NSError!)->Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            for object in objects {
                self.timelineCommentData.addObject(object)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.timelineCommentData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineCommentData = array.mutableCopy() as NSMutableArray

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    })
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return timelineCommentData.count + 1       //+1 is for displaying the topic

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let identifier = indexPath.row == 0 ? "storyCell" : "CommentCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as UITableViewCell

    if let storyCell = cell as? TopicTableViewCell{
     storyCell.titleLabel.text = topic?.objectForKey("title") as? String
     storyCell.contentLabel.text = topic?.objectForKey("content") as? String
     storyCell.timestampLabel.text = timeAgoSinceDate(topic!.createdAt, true)

    }
    storyCell.delegate = self
    }

    if let CommentCell = cell as? CommentsTableViewCell {
     let comment:PFObject = self.timelineCommentData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row - 1) as PFObject    ///// Is anything wrong here??
     var query = PFQuery(className: "Comment")
     query.whereKey("parent", equalTo:topic)


        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (objects:[AnyObject]!,error:NSError!)->Void in

            if (error == nil) {

                CommentCell.commentLabel.text = comment.objectForKey("commentContent") as? String   /////Or here
                CommentCell.timeLabel.text = timeAgoSinceDate(comment.createdAt, true)

            }
            else{

                println("no comment")
            }
        })


    CommentCell.delegate = self
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Found the answer, thanks everyone